# increment counter in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

This is the input XML:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

`<Item>` is an unbounded element which contains `<PackNumber>` as a child element. For each pack number we need to increment the counter variable, but here one condition is present like if previous `<PackNumber>` is equal to current `<PackNumber>` we have to ignore the counter (there is no need to increment) like below output.

Inside the `for-each`, can we  get the counter like below XSLT sample?

This is my XSLT template

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <A>
    <target>
      <xsl:for-each select="/inp1:Move-Afile/inp1:Afile/inp1:Item/inp1:PalletNumber">

        <xsl:variable name="count">
          <!-- get the count here-->
        </xsl:variable>

        <counter>$count</counter>
        <PNumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></PNumber>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </target>
  </A>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the XML output:

```
<A>
  <target>
    <Item>
      <counter>1</counter><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <PNumber>1234</PNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <counter>2</counter><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <PNumber>567</PNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is  equal to current <PackNumber> ignore the count-->no need to increment 
      <PNumber>567</PNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <counter>3</counter><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> increment the count-->
      <PNumber>126</PNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item><!-- if previous <PackNumber> is  equal to current <PackNumber> ignore the count-->no need to increment 
      <PNumber>126</PNumber>
    </Item>
  </target>
</A>
```

XML output 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
  <target>
    <counter>1</counter>
    <PNumber>1234</PNumber>
    <counter>2</counter>
    <PNumber>567</PNumber>
    <!-- IF PNumber is equal we have to ignore the Total loop -->
    <counter>3</counter>
    <PNumber>126</PNumber>
    <counter>4</counter>
    <PNumber>876</PNumber>
  </target>
</A>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Try this:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="text()" />

        <xsl:template match="PackNumber">
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding::PackNumber =.)" >
                <!-- if previous <PackNumber> is not equal to current <PackNumber> t-->

                <counter>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::PackNumber[not(preceding::PackNumber= .)])+1"/>
                </counter>
            </xsl:if>
            <PNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </PNumber>

        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <A>
            <target>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Item"/>
            </target>
        </A>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update** according the changed question:
*get the count here* (inside a for each loop as variable)
Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="text()" />

        <xsl:template match="PackNumber" mode="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::PackNumber
                          [not(preceding::PackNumber= .)and not( . = current()/. ) ])+1"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <A>
                <target>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Item/PackNumber">
                        <xsl:variable name="count">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="count"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                                <counter>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                                </counter>
                                <PNumber>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </PNumber>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </target>
            </A>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Update  Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
  <target>
    <counter>1</counter>
    <PNumber>1234</PNumber>
    <counter>2</counter>
    <PNumber>567</PNumber>
    <counter>2</counter>
    <PNumber>567</PNumber>
    <counter>3</counter>
    <PNumber>126</PNumber>
    <counter>4</counter>
    <PNumber>876</PNumber>
  </target>
</A>
```

Comment: this is working fine.can we modify this like above xslt type (take the counter value into the variable and assigned to target variable).which i added.

Comment: Sure no problem, but than you have always a count in your output.

Comment: please check the output2 which i added  above.

Comment: if PNumber is equal we have to ignore the loop like above output2.....can u pls modify this.

Comment: Put `<xsl:if test="not(preceding::PackNumber =.)" >` around  any thing you do not like to output. But now it looks like "GROUPING USING THE MUENCHIAN METHOD" would fit better. Is the original order of items impotent?

Comment: Also I do not understand why you like to use the for-each loop. The first part of my answer will also fit.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, though I would rather use Muenchian grouping here.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a short and very efficient solution, using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPackNByVal" match="PackNumber" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="Afile">
     <A>
       <target>
         <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "*/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kPackNByVal',.)[1])]"/>
       </target>
     </A>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="PackNumber">
   <counter><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></counter>
   <PNumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></PNumber>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<A>
   <target>
      <counter>1</counter>
      <PNumber>1234</PNumber>
      <counter>2</counter>
      <PNumber>567</PNumber>
      <counter>3</counter>
      <PNumber>126</PNumber>
      <counter>4</counter>
      <PNumber>876</PNumber>
   </target>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result you need is what you show in your *second* XML sample, then this stylesheet is all you need.

All it does is copy the `PackNumber` from only those `Item` elements that have no previous matching `PackNumber`.

The count is calculated as one more than the number of preceding `Item` elements that have no matching predecessor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <A>
      <target>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </target>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:if test="not(PackNumber = preceding-sibling::Item/PackNumber)">
      <counter>
        <xsl:value-of select="1+count(preceding-sibling::Item[not(PackNumber = preceding-sibling::Item/PackNumber)])"/>
      </counter>
      <xsl:copy-of select="PackNumber"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<A>
   <target>
      <counter>1</counter>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      <counter>2</counter>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <counter>3</counter>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
      <counter>4</counter>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
   </target>
</A>
```

Comment: Did you down vote my answer? Please notice that the question was changed three times in meantime. First was explicit to keep the duplicated PackNumner (as PNumber) only no count for duplicated . PackNumber. Second was how to do this inside a  for-each. Third was to remove PackNumber and count if duplicated.

Comment: I have no problem with your answer except that it is a bit long-winded. I also think you were overly-pliable to cooperate with every whim of the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using counter variable and attempting to increment its value every time (Which anyway not going to happen as the variables in xsl are actually constants), try using `position()`, which can work as a unique incrementing identifier. Following is an example of the syntax using `position()`:

```
<xsl:variable name="counterAlias" select="position()"/>
```