# How to count entries in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, symphony-cms

I am quite new to XSLT and I would like to generate a **count** of participants for a list of `events`. This is my XML:

```
<events>
    <event name="christmas"/>
    <event name="halloween"/>
    <event name="easter"/>
    <event name="easter"/>
</events>
```

What I need is something like this:

```
Christmas: 1 participant
Halloween: 1 participant
Easter: 2 participants
```

Can this be done with XSLT in any way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this stylesheet, which uses the **[Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** to group the `event` elements by their `@name`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- based on 
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/16509871/2115381 
    from Dimitre Novatchev
    --> 
    <xsl:key name="kEventVal" match="event" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="*">

            <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "event[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kEventVal',@name)[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="event">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('kEventVal',@name))"/>
    <xsl:text> participant</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="count(key('kEventVal',@name)) > 1 ">
        <xsl:text>s</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate following output:

```
christmas: 1 participant
halloween: 1 participant
easter: 2 participants
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try that. Just one question: What exactly does the `<xsl:key name="kEventVal" match="event" use="@name"/>` do? Is that some kind of external plugin?

Comment: That are two questions. ;-) 1. This generate something like a map wiht attribute name as key, and a list of all matching event elements as value. (E.g. have a look to http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp. 2. No plugin ore extension required. This xslt-1.0 .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It took me some time to read up on this, and I managed to get this working with a slightly modified code. I got stuck on one last detail though, so I posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572145/how-to-extend-a-muenchian-xml-grouping).