# How to improve my Muenchian grouping XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

Thanks to the help of [Niraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903389/niraj) and 
[hr_117](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115381/hr-117) I was able to arrive at an XSL template that turns this XML...

```
<bookings>
  <entry>
    <event>Christmas</event>
    <attendees>2</attendees>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <event>Halloween</event>
    <attendees>2</attendees>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <event>Easter</event>
    <attendees>1</attendees>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <event>Easter</event>
    <attendees>1</attendees>
  </entry>
</bookings>
```

...into this output:

> Christmas: 1 booking(s)
>
> Halloween: 1 booking(s)
>
> Easter: 2 booking(s)

This is my XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="bookings"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="bookings-within-period" match="bookings/entry" use="event" />

<xsl:template match="bookings">
  <xsl:for-each select="entry[count(. | key('bookings-within-period', event)[1]) = 1]">
      <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(event,': ')" />
          <xsl:value-of select="count(key('bookings-within-period', event))" />
          <xsl:text> booking(s)</xsl:text>          
      </p>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I get this function to calculate the **sum** of `attendees` as well?

This is the output I need:

> Christmas: 1 booking(s), 2 attendee(s)
>
> Halloween: 1 booking(s), 2 attendee(s)
>
> Easter: 2 booking(s), 2 attendee(s)

Thanks to anybody who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhanced XSLT is as under:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bookings"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="bookings-within-period" match="bookings/entry" use="event" />

  <xsl:template match="bookings">
    <xsl:for-each select="entry[count(. | key('bookings-within-period', event)[1]) = 1]">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(event,': ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('bookings-within-period', event))" />
        <xsl:text> booking(s), </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('bookings-within-period', event)/attendees)" />
        <xsl:text> attendee(s)</xsl:text>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where we have `<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('bookings-within-period', event)/attendees)" />` to sum all the attendees

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! Just one last thing: Let's assume each `<event>` had a `<date>` node as well. Would it be possible to sort the output by date then?

Answer (score 3):

Using `key('bookings-within-period', event)` gives you the `entry` element in each group and then `sum(key('bookings-within-period', event)/attendees)` gives you the sum of the `attendees` in each group.

And you need to do that inside the `for-each` where the first `entry` element in each group is the context node, in case that is not clear.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that before but it turns out I couldn't see the wood for all the trees. I just threw a coin and `Navin` won, so I marked his answer as the right one ;-)